# How to get accurate predictions from Neural Network?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, prediction

I'm doing a project on water quality prediction using Artificial Neural Network. I implemented this using python. I have completed my prediction model but the generated predictions are not much accurate.

What I'm doing is I have collected data from a river for past 4 and half years on daily basis and I'm predicting a pattern for a specific parameter by inputting data from past records. Simply what I need to do is to predict "Turbidity level" of water on 2015 by feeding data on turbidity from 2012-2014.

From the model which I have created it is not much accurate when I compare to the real data I have gathered for 2015. Please help me to solve this. I tried this by changing hidden layer sizes and the Lambda value.

```
//This is my code

import xlrd
import numpy as np
from numpy import zeros
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy import optimize

#Neural Network

class Neural_Network(object):

    def __init__(self,Lambda):        
        #Define Hyperparameters
        self.inputLayerSize = 2
        self.outputLayerSize = 1
        self.hiddenLayerSize = 10
        #Weights (parameters)
        self.W1 = np.random.randn(self.inputLayerSize,self.hiddenLayerSize)
        self.W2 = np.random.randn(self.hiddenLayerSize,self.outputLayerSize)

        #Regularization Parameter:
        self.Lambda = Lambda

    def forward(self, arrayInput):
        #Propogate inputs though network
        self.z2 = np.dot(arrayInput, self.W1)
        self.a2 = self.sigmoid(self.z2)
        self.z3 = np.dot(self.a2, self.W2)
        yHat = self.sigmoid(self.z3) 
        return yHat

    def sigmoid(self, z):
        #Apply sigmoid activation function to scalar, vector, or matrix
        return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))

    def sigmoidPrime(self,z):
        #Gradient of sigmoid
        return np.exp(-z)/((1+np.exp(-z))**2)

    def costFunction(self, arrayInput, arrayOutput):
        #Compute cost for given input,output use weights already stored in class.       
        self.yHat = self.forward(arrayInput)
        #J = 0.5*sum((arrayOutput-self.yHat)**2)
        #J = 0.5*sum((arrayOutput-self.yHat)**2)/arrayInput.shape[0] + (self.Lambda/2)
        J = 0.5*sum((arrayOutput-self.yHat)**2)/arrayInput.shape[0] + (self.Lambda/2)*sum(sum(self.W1**2),sum(self.W2**2))
        #J = 0.5*sum((arrayOutput-self.yHat)**2)/arrayInput.shape[0] + (self.Lambda/2)*(sum(self.W1**2)+sum(self.W2**2))       
        return J

    def costFunctionPrime(self, arrayInput, arrayOutput):
        #Compute derivative with respect to W and W2 for a given X and y:
        self.yHat = self.forward(arrayInput)

        delta3 = np.multiply(-(arrayOutput-self.yHat), self.sigmoidPrime(self.z3))
        #Add gradient of regularization term:
        #dJdW2 = np.dot(self.a2.T, delta3) + self.Lambda*self.W2
        dJdW2 = np.dot(self.a2.T, delta3)

        delta2 = np.dot(delta3, self.W2.T)*self.sigmoidPrime(self.z2)
        #Add gradient of regularization term:
        #dJdW1 = np.dot(arrayInput.T, delta2)+ self.Lambda*self.W1
        dJdW1 = np.dot(arrayInput.T, delta2)  

        return dJdW1, dJdW2

    #Helper Functions for interacting with other classes:
    def getParams(self):
        #Get W1 and W2 unrolled into vector:
        params = np.concatenate((self.W1.ravel(), self.W2.ravel()))
        return params

    def setParams(self, params):
        #Set W1 and W2 using single paramater vector.
        W1_start = 0
        W1_end = self.hiddenLayerSize * self.inputLayerSize
        self.W1 = np.reshape(params[W1_start:W1_end], (self.inputLayerSize , self.hiddenLayerSize))
        W2_end = W1_end + self.hiddenLayerSize*self.outputLayerSize
        self.W2 = np.reshape(params[W1_end:W2_end], (self.hiddenLayerSize, self.outputLayerSize))

    def computeGradients(self, arrayInput, arrayOutput):
        dJdW1, dJdW2 = self.costFunctionPrime(arrayInput, arrayOutput)        
        return np.concatenate((dJdW1.ravel(), dJdW2.ravel()))

    def computeNumericalGradient(self,N, X, y):
        paramsInitial = N.getParams()        
        numgrad = np.zeros(paramsInitial.shape)
        perturb = np.zeros(paramsInitial.shape)
        e = 1e-4

        for p in range(len(paramsInitial)):
            #Set perturbation vector
            perturb[p] = e
            N.setParams(paramsInitial + perturb)
            loss2 = N.costFunction(X, y)

            N.setParams(paramsInitial - perturb)
            loss1 = N.costFunction(X, y)

            #Compute Numerical Gradient
            numgrad[p] = (loss2 - loss1) / (2*e)            

            #Return the value we changed to zero:
            perturb[p] = 0

        #Return Params to original value:
        N.setParams(paramsInitial)
        return numgrad

#Trainer class    
class trainer(object):
    def __init__(self, N):
        self.N = N

    def costFunctionWrapper(self, params, arrayInput, arrayOutput):
        self.N.setParams(params)
        cost = self.N.costFunction(arrayInput, arrayOutput)
        #grad = self.N.computeGradients(arrayInput, arrayOutput)
        grad = self.N.computeNumericalGradient(self.N,arrayInput, arrayOutput)
        return cost, grad

    def callbackF(self, params):
        self.N.setParams(params)
        self.J.append(self.N.costFunction(self.arrayInput, self.arrayOutput))
        self.testJ.append(self.N.costFunction(self.TestInput, self.TestOutput))

    def train(self, arrayInput, arrayOutput,TestInput,TestOutput):
        #Make an internal variable for the callback function:
        self.arrayInput = arrayInput
        self.arrayOutput = arrayOutput

        self.TestInput = TestInput
        self.TestOutput = TestOutput

        #Make empty list to store costs:
        self.J = []
        self.testJ= []

        params0 = self.N.getParams()

        options = {'maxiter': 200, 'disp' : True}
        _res = optimize.minimize(self.costFunctionWrapper, params0, jac=True, method='BFGS', \
                                 args=(arrayInput, arrayOutput), options=options, callback=self.callbackF)

        self.N.setParams(_res.x)
        self.optimizationResults = _res



#Main Program   

path = "F:\prototype\\newdata\\tody\\turbidity\\c.xlsx"
book = xlrd.open_workbook(path)

input1=[]
output=[]
testinput=[]
testoutput=[]

#training data set
first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(1)
for row in range(first_sheet.ncols-1):
    input1.append(first_sheet.col_values(row))

for row in range((first_sheet.ncols-1),first_sheet.ncols ):
    output.append(first_sheet.col_values(row))

arrayInput = np.asarray(input1)
arrayInput = arrayInput.T
arrayOutput = np.asarray(output)
arrayOutput = arrayOutput.T

#testing data set
first_sheet1 = book.sheet_by_index(0)
for row in range(first_sheet1.ncols-1):
    testinput.append(first_sheet1.col_values(row))

for row in range((first_sheet1.ncols-1),first_sheet1.ncols ):
    testoutput.append(first_sheet1.col_values(row))

TestInput = np.asarray(testinput)
TestInput = TestInput.T
TestOutput = np.asarray(testoutput)
TestOutput = TestOutput.T

#2016
input2016=[]
first_sheet2 = book.sheet_by_index(2)
for row in range(first_sheet2.ncols):
    input2016.append(first_sheet2.col_values(row))

Input = np.asarray(input2016)
Input = Input.T

# Scaling
arrayInput = arrayInput / np.amax(arrayInput, axis=0)
arrayOutput = arrayOutput / np.amax(arrayOutput, axis=0)

TestInput = TestInput / np.amax(TestInput, axis=0)
Input = Input / np.amax(Input, axis=0)
TestOutput = TestOutput / np.amax(TestOutput, axis=0)

NN=Neural_Network(Lambda=0.00000000000001)

T = trainer(NN)
T.train(arrayInput,arrayOutput,TestInput,TestOutput)


print NN.costFunctionPrime(arrayInput,arrayOutput)

Output =  NN.forward(Input)
print Output
print '----------'
#print TestOutput

#plt.plot(T.J)
plt.plot(Output)
plt.grid(1)
plt.xlabel('Iterations')
plt.ylabel('cost')
plt.show()
```

//Turbidity means 2015 real data and prediction means data predicted using this code[image]

Comment: Sigmoid has the output range '[0, 1]'. You need to scale the target values

Comment: I have scaled my inputs and outputs. Is there any scaling necessary t sigmoid function?

Comment: Then revert the scaling of the predictions of the image, else we have no idea how to make a fair comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the comments suggest scaling the output sigmoidal layer to match the correct data. If you look at your predictions, you will see that with some scaling they are pretty accurate. I advise against scaling a sigmoidal function, however.

A sigmoidal output is meant to be interpreted as a probability (given certain constraints are followed), so scaling it would be breaking that contract and could give undefined results. What happens if you scale from 0-100, but then start receiving training targets larger than 100? (assuming you are training an online system, otherwise perhaps that example is not relevant)

I would change your code to use a linear output layer. This would not require any manipulation of the data after training the network. Also given that your cost function is least squares, the linear output layer will be convex (which reduces the number of local optima that your algorithm can get stuck in).

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. I'll try to change according to that.